# Class cast exception using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I just want to retrieve list of data but by using below code why i get class cast exception...

```
public List<TbDiscussionForumAnswere> findTbDiscussionForumAnswerebyforumQuestionId(Integer forumQuestionId) {
session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
TbDiscussionForumAnswere TbDiscussionForumAnswere = (TbDiscussionForumAnswere)session.createCriteria(TbDiscussionForumAnswere.class)                .add(Restrictions.eq("forumQuestionId.forumQuestionId", forumQuestionId));
return (List<TbDiscussionForumAnswere>) TbDiscussionForumAnswere.getTbDiscussionForumAnswereCollection();
}
```

above method gives me below exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl cannot be cast to com.medikm.entity.TbDiscussionForumAnswere
```

Thank u

Comment: did you check our answers? please accept an answer. thnx!

Answer (score 1):

you are creating a `Criteria` object not a `TbDiscussionForumAnswere` object. this is a correct error message. 
You use this `Criteria` class to execute a query. you should cast it to `Criteria` class

Answer (score 1):

`session.createCriteria(TbDiscussionForumAnswere.class).add(Restrictions.eq("forumQuestionId.forumQuestionId", forumQuestionId));` Returns an Critera not and object `TbDiscussionForumAnswere`

so you have to Change the line to:

```
Critera critera  = (Critera)session.createCriteria(TbDiscussionForumAnswere.class).add(Restrictions.eq("forumQuestionId.forumQuestionId", forumQuestionId));
```

Answer (score 0):

below code i use and this works fine for me thank you all for your answers

```
List<TbDiscussionForumAnswere> tbDiscussionForumAnswereList = session.createCriteria(TbDiscussionForumAnswere.class)
.add(Restrictions.eq("forumQuestionId.forumQuestionId",forumQuestionId))
.setFetchMode("forumQuestionId", FetchMode.LAZY)
.list();
```

Comment: please accept at least one answer so as the question to be considered closed.

Comment: also consider upvoting the answers that helped you with your problem. this is the "reward" for the people that spent sometime helping you! regards